# Minecraft modding: onLanded and item type/positioning?

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, modding

My question is about programming Minecraft mods. So i added a block to my Mod. Now I want, that when you drop a sugar on it, that it waits some time and then, if the sugar is still there, it will consume the sugar and spawn an item that i made for my mod. But I don't know how to test wether the item is sugar. I use the event onLanded with an

```
@Override
public void onLanded(World worldIn, Entity entityIn)
{
    if(entityIn instanceof EntityItem && !worldIn.isRemote)
    {

    }
}                                                                                             }
```

but I don't know where to specify the item and where to get the position of the block.

I hope anyone can help me and sorry for my bad english I'm not a native speaker. Thank you in advance Nova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried it but to be more precise you could write:

```
//specialBlock is the 
//block on which the sugar is supposed to react on
if(specialBlock.getLocation().getBlock().getRelative(BlockFace.UP) != null && 
   entityIn instance of Item.sugar) {

}
```

I called your block here **specialBlock**.
Now you check if there is something on your block and if it is sugar..

Comment: The problem is: how do I know the position of the entity?

Comment: Do you want the x position? entity.posX would be attribute